# Using "ñ" in a JS file

Tags: javascript, forms

I have this form dropdown thats populated by a JS file. One of the options in my dropdown has the character **ñ**, but instead of the showing the letter it shows this: �.

How can I get the form to show the letter ñ? (something like an ascii code but for JS?)

thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you tried switching the encoding in the JS file to UTF-8? (Assuming you use UTF-8 on your site in general)

Comment: Can we see your code? What is the character encoding of your page? Javascript will handle that character as a string.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First of all, fixing the encoding of the page (to UTF-8, preferably with `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>` directly after `<head>`) and making sure your editor is set to UTF-8 is generally a very good idea.

Otherwise, replacing ñ with **`\u00f1`** (in JavaScript code, not HTML) is the way to go.

If the JavaScript gets the ñ from an HTML or XML document, you can also use `&#x00f1;` or `&ntilde;` there.

Comment: I changed the "ñ" to \u00f1 and it worked. thanks. I also changed my encoding and now the other characters that weren't showing (accent marks, since the page im doing is in Spanish) appear. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You probably have wrong charset on your page. Check if you have something similar to this in your `<head>` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

You need to have it UTF-8 encoded to see characters contained in it.

@phihag mentioned correctly that this answer will be only correct if the script is inline. For external scripts, you must ensure, that file is also UTF-8 encoded or include entity such as `&ntilde;`.

Comment: This will only help if the script is inline.

Comment: What do you mean by "inline"?

Comment: @Tomasz Kowalczyk `<script>/* code */</script>` instead of `<script src="...">`

Comment: @zack, this is not true. It works on included source files as well.

Comment: I thought charset declarations didn't inherit from the document to external scripts, but I could be wrong.  I certainly wouldn't rely on it.  (The 100% scrupulously correct thing is to get the server to put `Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8` in the HTTP headers *for the script*, but I understand this is often harder than it ought to be.)

Answer (score 2):

You should use UTF-8 in your page, as mentioned several times by other answers and comments.

For the actual character, you can either use the HTML entity `&ntilde` (again, as answered by others) or `&#241;` or `&#xF1;` (in HTML -- or in a JS string going to be inserted in or parsed as HTML), or the escaped UTF-8 value `\u00F1` (in a JS string).

Comment: HTML entities only work if the contents of the string are going to be fed to the HTML parser, like via "innerHTML" or something like that.

Comment: That's what I meant, but I realise the ambiguity. Fixed it.

Comment: I figured you knew that because of that second paragraph, but I wanted to clarify it; questions about why it doesn't work to use an HTML entity to set the "value" of an input come up sometimes :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the character code:

```
var babyGirl = "ni\u00f1a";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually an HTML Entities issue. You need to provide the HTML entity instead of the character.

See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp

Specifically: &nt ilde; (minus the space) -> ñ

Comment: -1 for linking to w3schools, which is notoriously out of date and riddled with errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use `&ntilde;` See [here](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/latin1.html)

Comment: This will only help if the script is inline. (@Zack, you don't charge royalties, do you?)

Comment: HTML entities only work if the contents of the string are going to be fed to the HTML parser, like via "innerHTML" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try the html entity for the character

```
&ntilde;
```

Comment: This will only help if the script is inline.

Comment: Are you sure? I just had to translate jquery.dataTables.js, which has arrays with words (Forward, Empty Table, etc) to Portuguese, using entities, and it works.

Comment: @nosuchnick Absolutely. You're probably using jQuery to construct DOM nodes from serialized HTML, which is an exception in what it works. Pure ECMA/JavaScript has not notion of XML entities.

Comment: @KOGI Could you back that up with a source? I cannot find a single mention of "entity", HTML/XML or otherwise, in ECMA-262. Also the trivial example `<!doctype html><script src="t.js"></script>` and t.js: `alert("&ntilde;");` produces a literal &ntilde; and not ñ.

Comment: Use your same setup you mentioned, except instead of alert try `document.write( '&ntilde;' );` or if you have jQuery, try `$('<div />').appendTo( 'body' ).text( '&ntilde;' );` Both work just fine. And seeing as the original question was regarding the display of a dropdown, this should be sufficient for his needs.

Comment: @KOGI Doesn't that exactly match my "not true" description of `construct(ing) DOM nodes from serialized HTML/XML`? And that is only extremely rarely a good idea, especially if the options are variable and therefore come from untrusted sources.